# Show date on input field in a different format than value

Tags: html, date, formatting

I create a webapplication which works with the search engine elasticsearch.
In elasticsearch I save dates in a yyyy-MM-dd format. In my webapplication I want to use regional settings to show the date in a comfortable way for the current user, like dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy. This needs to happen in a dynamic way.

An example is:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="queryBankCommunicationDateFrom" name="queryBankCommunicationDateFrom" value="2015-11-30"/>
```

Now my question is, how can I show dates in an input field different than the real value (which I use to search in elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 0):

Then type must be eg:type="date" and make sure your using  updated web browser
that supports html5